IOS | You do not have required contracts to perform an operation
While uploading IOS app using transporter to App Store Connect I am getting below error.

You do not have required contracts to perform an operation.

this was the response object.
{
    "id" : "*****************************",
    "status" : "403",
    "code" : "FORBIDDEN_ERROR.CONTRACT_NOT_VALID",
    "title" : "You do not have required contracts to perform an operation",
    "detail" : "You do not have required contracts to perform an operation."
  }

The distribution certificate on my mac machine is valid and not expired. There was no errors in archiving ipa.
below is the transporter app screenshot.


Did you accept the new agreement on the developer site?

I have same problem.
I am seeing on appstoreconnect page in business section, that new agreement for free apps is available.

hi @snole, thanks for this. This fixed the issue.

The issue has been fixed by accepting the new agreement.
Thankyou community .

Go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/business/ choose your business and agree to the newest contract

This issue comes when you try to sign or upload iOS application to TestFlight or App Store.
You will face this issue wherever there is a new license agreement updated by Apple.
To solve this,
You just need to login to https://developer.apple.com and Accept the Terms and conditions.
If you are sub-developer for that account, please contact your Admin/account holder.

NOTE: Wait for couple of minutes after Accepting T&C and start uploading builds.
